# Regexp matching 3 consecutive capital letters

Tags: php, regex

i have the following text :

> 74 avenue Emile Counor
>
> Bat B2 Appt B104

I want to replace all line feed, only if **the following 3 letters are not 3 capitals**.

For example, the previous example should become:

> 74 avenue Emile Counor Bat B2 Appt B104

but

> 74 avenue Emile Counor
>
> BAT B2 Appt B104

should stay.

I have tried many solutions via regexp tools, but impossible to match what i want.

Here what i have tried so far

```
preg_replace("/\n([^A-Z]{3})/", " $1", $str)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to negate what is following the LF, the way is to use a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$str = preg_replace("/\n(?![A-Z]{3})/", " ", $str);
```

Note that a lookahead is only a test and that its content doesn't appear in the match result.

Comment: i think the input contains an extra blank line in the middle.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: no, it's only a bad formatting in the post.

Answer (score 3):

Search regex:

```
'/\n(?![A-Z]{3})/'
```

Replacement:

```
" "
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rO9iN0/1)

**Code:**

```
$str = "74 avenue Emile Counor\nBat B2 Appt B104";     
$result = preg_replace('/\n(?![A-Z]{3})/', ' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple approach.

Find:

```
 (\n[A-Z]{3})|\n
```

Replace:

```
 $1
```

Further, there is no *simple way* to preserve/add the extra space format character here.
I mean it can be done via a callback, but adding a blind `" "` is wrong.